# How to use pointer array which contains multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, multidimensional-array

I'm making socoban game in C++ now. I'd like to know how can I make a pointer array which can contains multidimensional vectors.

For example,
I created some 2-demension vectors

```cpp
vector<vector<char> > vector1;
vector<vector<char> > vector2;
```

I want to make a pointer
For example `(pointer)[0] = &vector1`
like this

Please tell me how.

Comment: `vector<vector<char>>* arr[] = { &vector1, &vector2 };` is this what you want to do?

Comment: Seems not necessary to use pointer arrays, just pass the reference of vectors.

Comment: There is, of course, the question of why you want an array of pointers in the first place - which you haven't described. `vector<vector<char> > *pointer [] = {&vector1, &vector2}` will mean the values of `pointer[0]` and `pointer[1]` are `&vector1` and `&vector2` respectively.  Whether such a construct is a good idea or not depends on what you intend to do with `pointer` (or `pointer[0]` or `pointer[1]`).  There circumstances in which an array of pointers is useful, but other circumstances where alternatives are better, and other circumstances in which it is completely the wrong option.